# odoo - 'Field origin does not exist'

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

This is my code:

```
   <record id="view_order_form_inline" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[11]" position="after">
                    <field name="xx_insurance_inline"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

This is to add a new column inside the sales order lines.
When updating my module i get the following error:

```
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Field `origin` does not exist

Error context:
View `sale.order.line form`
[view_id: 1035, xml_id: n/a, model: sale.order.line, parent_id: 647]" while parsing /home/pantera/Custom/xx_khleuven2/view/sale.xml:24, near
<record id="view_order_form_inline" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[11]" position="after">
                    <field name="xx_insurance_inline"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Since there is nowhere in my code a reference to a field called *origin* I have no idea what the exact problem is.
Should adding the column be done in a different way or am i overlooking something obvious?

edit:
This is the xml code where the xpath refers to:

```
<field name="order_line">
    <form string="Sales Order Lines">
    ....
    </form>
    <tree string="Sales Order Lines" editable="bottom">
         <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
         <field name="state" invisible="1"/>
         <field name="th_weight" invisible="1"/>
         <field name="product_id"
                                        context="{'partner_id':parent.partner_id, 'quantity':product_uom_qty, 'pricelist':parent.pricelist_id, 'uom':product_uom}"
                                        groups="base.group_user"
                                        on_change="product_id_change(parent.pricelist_id, product_id, product_uom_qty, False, product_uos_qty, False, name, parent.partner_id, False, True, parent.date_order, False, parent.fiscal_position, False, context)"/>
               <field name="name"/>
               <field name="product_uom_qty"
                                        context="{'partner_id':parent.partner_id, 'quantity':product_uom_qty, 'pricelist':parent.pricelist_id, 'uom':product_uom}"
                                        on_change="product_id_change(parent.pricelist_id, product_id, product_uom_qty, product_uom, product_uos_qty, product_uos, name, parent.partner_id, False, False, parent.date_order, False, parent.fiscal_position, True, context)"/>
                <field name="product_uom"
                                        on_change="product_uom_change(parent.pricelist_id, product_id, product_uom_qty, product_uom, product_uos_qty, product_uos, name, parent.partner_id, False, False, parent.date_order, context)"
                                        groups="product.group_uom" options='{"no_open": True}'/>
               <field name="product_uos_qty" groups="product.group_uos" invisible="1"/>
               <field name="product_uos" string="UoS" groups="product.group_uos" invisible="1"/>
               <field name="price_unit"/>
               <field name="tax_id" widget="many2many_tags" domain="[('parent_id','=',False),('type_tax_use','&lt;&gt;','purchase')]"/>
               <field name="discount" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line"/>
               <field name="price_subtotal"/>
       </tree>
  </field>
```

Comment: have you solved this? I have same problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to update few things in xml,

```
<field name="model">sale.order</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
<field name="priority" eval="50" />
```

Because this external id `sale.view_order_form` is belongs to sale.order model not to sale.order.line model.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you have is modified any of the view which is adding some field base don origin or removed the **origin** field from original record. Originally in database there are total Three views of the **sale.order** model who is altering or adding the origin view as show below image :

[image]

1. **sale.order.form** is adding the origin field.
2. **sale.order.inherit** is : is inhering view **1** and using **origin** field added. This will be their only if module **sale_crm** is installed.
3. **sale.order.journal.view.form_** : is inhering view **1** and using **origin** field added. This will be their only if module **sale_journal** is installed.

So make sure that this view exist indatabse correctly before upadting your module.

Bests